# Apply global attribute variants of a configurable product?

Tags: configurable-product, ce-1.8.1.0, filter

Can Magento CE 1.8.1.0 apply global attribute variants of a configurable product?

Size: My global attribute for configurable product
For example: Test (Default configurable product)
Test-small (Different size, simple product associated of test)
Test-medium (Different size, simple product associated of test)
Test-large (different size, simple product associated of test)

My problem is if I filter small size I want to "test" product returned, not "test-small"

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Layered navigation and indexing, indexes all attributes from all simple products associated with the configurable.

Therefore you can just create a configurable product, add all simple products and your configurable is found, when searched for small, medium and  large.

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand your question? It is too narrow. What are you trying to achieve overall? Magento has methods to return an array of associated products given a simple product id.

```
`Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($productId)`;
```

There is also a function to get the associated simple product IDs from a configurable product ID

```
//returns an array of array[ID]=>"ID" pairs
$childIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($productConfigurable->getId(), true);
```

I suggest some additional logic in your code to analyse your collection and extract what you want from the collection - you don't need to filter the collection so precisely because a couple of foreach loops will allow you to access what you need.

If you are concerned about speed then put the results of your foreach loops into the Magento Cache.

Comment: In this example If I filter for "small size" I want to get "test" product, not "test-small" product. This is what I meant.

Comment: Then I don't know a better way other than building a collection to get the simple products that match "small size" and using `getParentIdsByChild()` to retrieve the configurable.

Comment: But If I filter "small, medium, large" size, they will be return configurable product 3 times. It doesnt make sense. Right? @Malachy I'm trying to find better way.

Comment: Do you want it to just return one configurable? I don't know the details. You can just code to remove the duplicates using a foreach loop. I don't know a better way; maybe if you rewrote the resource model but I hardly think it is worth it. I have learned not to fight Magento - Work with what it gives you and add your own manipulation if you can't get what you want from a single collection call. I notice you are using `Mage::getResourceModel('reports/product_collection')` and not `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')` maybe that makes a difference if you can use it.